# What is this type of tree?

Tags: trees, tree-identification

Wondering if you know what type of tree are those two?

[image]

[image]

Comment: picture taken today in Bulgaria

Comment: Any chance of closer pictures of the leaves and bark? The middle tree in the top image might be a silver birch, and the one in the background of the second is possibly a conifer of some sort.

Comment: yes, a photo of the bark would help. Maybe a weeping variant of some tree.

Comment: also check over on Gardening and Landscaping if you haven't already. They're great at Tree ID.

Comment: Which two trees in particular are you interested in? It is not clear to me which ones are of need of identification. Sorry, but it may only be me.

Comment: @THEGreatGatsby Is that in Varna, perhaps?

Comment: Sofia it is actually

Answer (score 2):

Hard to identify from the pictures, but I am pretty sure it is a birch tree.
The white spots on the bark and the structure of the leafs are a good indicators.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch

Comment: Definitely birch on the first picture. As for the leaves on the second picture, I'd have bet it's beech, but appearently some birch varieties have more rounded leaves that look like beech leaves. The "needly" one in the back might be yew.